Angular TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter
I am getting this error from event emitter @output
From child component
import { EventEmitter } from 'stream';
.....
@Output() selectedData = new EventEmitter<any>();
.....
this.selectedData .emit(data);

Parent component
From html file
<html-tag-of-child (selectedData)="selectedData($event)">  </html-tag-of-child>
.....

from ts file
selectedData($event){
console.log("event", $event");
}


Import is wrong, Actually i imported from vs code suggestion, it was from stream, But It should be from angular/core.
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

